# 1970s or 1980s movie where people's heads would explode in their sleep

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

There was a movie, either in the late 70's or early 80's about a virus that, once you were infected with it if you fell asleep your brain would swell so badly that it would pop out of your head.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with this?

Comment: There was a series on channel 4. It was something like it came from outer space and the main character looked like donald sutherland. But I can't find it either

Answer (score 9):

This is [**The Alpha Incident**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alpha_Incident) from 1978, a classic sci-fi movie.

Trapped in a railway station people struggle to stay awake, for if they fall asleep - even for a minute - the virus strikes and their brains swell and explode out of the skull.

The hero manages to stay awake the longest and inadvertently falls asleep and wakes up - he is fine. He is cured. The cure - to stay awake for 3 days (if I remember correctly). He tries to explain and shout to the decontamination unit when it arrives the cure is to stay awake - but they don't listen and shoot and burn the station. So the virus is out there and nobody knows the cure is to stay awake for 3 days.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it was the late '70s or early '80s?

This sounds like an *exact match* for **Autocraniotomous** by the group **NightOwls**, a short film created as part of the 2013 48Hours film making competition (all films made within 48 hours).

A virus called 'Exploding Head Syndrome' has infected a lot of people. When they go to sleep, their heads explode.

The protagonist finds out there has been a cure discovered for Exploding Head Syndrome, publically available the next week, and must stay awake until he can get the cure.

> Vic Meyer goes to the doctor feeling funny and finds out he has 'Autocraniotomous' or 'Exploding Head Syndrome' as they use on the street. He seeks out a support group with other sufferers of 'EHS' and finds love in another member of the group. They must now beat the clock and stay awake or their heads may explode.
>   <sup><sub>- [Autocraniotomous (2013) - Plot Summary - IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2976226/plotsummary)</sub></sup>

The heads of the characters in this film actually explode, causing the sufferers to wear helmets/plastics bags around their head to keep it tidy when they fall asleep.

Check it out at the [48Hours website](http://www.48hours.co.nz/screening-room/2013/auckland/autocraniotomous/), or view the [video](http://player.vimeo.com/video/67181541).

Comment: Even if this isn't the right answer, kudos for coming up with a solid match.