# 2000s/2010s movie about contagious virus/disease that causes people's brains to explode

Tags: story-identification, movie, virus

I'm looking for a movie where I can only remember the opening scene; it's of a man in a forest who is clearly in pain clutching and scratching at his head screaming until his head explodes. The whole movie is centred around this disease/virus causing this sickness which ultimately ends in the brain exploding of whoever has it.

It's an early 2010's/ late 2000's movie.

Comment: *Scanners* remake/sequel?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93620/1970s-or-1980s-movie-where-peoples-heads-would-explode-in-their-sleep

Comment: Thank you for this! but I read up on Scanners and the movie that I am looking for may have been inspired by it but it's not a remake or sequel of it. :(

Comment: The pilot of *Max Headroom* had "Blipverts", rapid-fire subliminal adverts that could cause the heads of some viewers to explode. I think the victims were still indoors when it happened, though.

Answer (score 2):

Partial match: *Antisocial* (2013).

From [the reviews on IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2772092/reviews):

> A satire like Dead Set.
>
> Apparently, a social media site uses subliminal to draw members back. Unfortunately, **that program mutates into a virus that affects human brains. Turning people delusional and violence. To the point where a tumour grows and some heads explode.**
>
> Lots' of frights and gore. As usual, the survivors barricade themselves in a house and fall one by one. As the survivors frantically check the social site for news, they are infected too.

The time of release matches, as do the exploding heads and worldwide contagion, but the opening scene is not set in a forest. Haven't checked the whole movie, but it's still possible there's a forest scene later on.

Warning: trailer is NSFW (gore, woman in underwear):

---

Found with the Google query `science fiction movie virus head explodes site:imdb.com/title`, page 2 of the results.